# Having Problems with a PHP Contact Form Inside DIV Set to Display:none by Default

Tags: php, forms, html, contacts

We're using PHP to build a product page for a gallery website that's using GetSimple 3.0 CMS. We are trying to create a contact form that is displayed when you click a button. By default the contact form is in a DIV that's set to display: none. When you click the button it displays: block. When a user clicks the submit button for the form and calls the action it loads the contact.php file and resets the DIV to display: none resulting in the user not seeing the conformation text that their form was submitted. You can only see it by clicking on the contact button again and displaying that DIV to block manually.

We'd like the contact form DIV to persist after the submit button is clicked. I don't think showing our code would be helpful. We're just trying to find a way to implement this idea if possible.

At present our website is still early in it's development stage and it's still being hosted locally.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So basically you want the form to be automatically shown after the user has used it at least once? Like, the PHP file that handles the form submission returns the user to the same form?

Comment: thats basically true. The contact.php file is part of a plugin that establishes the text fields being used for the form then upon submit,  validates the form information. If the form is filled it properly, the form is hidden and replaced by a div that has a thank you/ confirmation message. If any of the fields were not properly filled out, the validator catches it and displays text as to what they need to do to fix what they typed. In any scenario, upon clicking the submit button it loads the content.php page and then div containing the form returns to display:none; instead of remaining block.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax submission of that particular form so that focus will not loss even the page will not be refreshed

Comment: Consider adding some detail to your answer. What do you mean? How would he do that? Give some example code.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: Completely changed to reflect new information obtained to more directly address the problem.*

Reading your above comments I'm fairly confident we are looking at the wrong function to edit. The wrapper element is not present in the function you posted which is what needs to have it's display toggled.

once you find that block of code we can edit it to look for the presence of post data which would indicate that the page is being loaded after a form submission has occurred (I can't promise that this won't cause it to trigger at the wrong time if there is more than one form on this page) and write in a style attribute to overwrite the default value if tested true.

Some where in that plugin there will be something defining the forms wrapper element

```
$html = '<div id="some-unique-id" class="some-class-name">';
```

You can break up this line and put a test for post data adding an inline style attribute if found

```
$html = '<div id="some-unique-id" class="some-class-name"'; //tag left open

if(isset($_POST) && (count($_POST))){ //Some Post Data Exists
  $html .= ' style="display:block;"'; //Add display overwrite
}//Some Post Data Exists

$html .= '>'; //close the tag
```

The test we are performing here is `if(isset($_POST) && (count($_POST))){` which is checking to make sure that A) `$_POST` exists and B) it has at least one element (this is using type juggling to convert a numeric result from `count()` into its Boolean equivalent *(where anything greater than 0 will test `true`)*

Now, as i mentioned, there may be more than one form on this page and it is possible it will be displayed afterwards which would auto show your contact form when you don't want to have it showing. Based on the example you provided in a comment it looks like this function exists within a class. If the block of code we are looking for exists within the same class it might be possible to leverage the `id` attribute to restrict the check to post data from the form you are interested.

```
$html = '<div id="some-unique-id" class="some-class-name"';

//Check for contact form specific post data 
//(if $this->id is within scope and still the same)
if(isset($_POST) && (isset($_POST['p01-contact' . $this->id]))){
  $html .= ' style="display:block;"'; //Add display overwrite
}//Post Data Exists

$html .= '>';
```

In this test we are hoping that `$this` exists and the attribute `id` of `$this` is the same as it was at the time that the form was originally drawn so we can look for post data that is related to the specific contact form. *(the name we are looking for is based off of the code example you posted as a comment)*

Unfortunately without looking at the source of the site/plugin it will be impossible for me to tell you where you can find what you are looking for. Once you find it though one of these two scenarios should hopefully take care of your problem.

Is this a publicly available plugin we could look at or something developed in-house?

Comment: Ajax really isn't in the picture because I know less about that than I do PHP. The iframe solution was something we considered earlier, but couldn't really find an elegant way to work it in.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit PHP code used for building the page, you can always display the style dynamically depending on the request, like this:

```
<div style="display:<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['answer'])) ? 'block' : 'none';?>>
    Thank you!
</div>
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="answer" />
     ...
</form>
```

You can also submit a form without reloading the page, e.g. with JQuery.Forms

Answer (score 0):

*If* both the form and the PHP file are located in *Contact.php*, you could consider using this:

```
<div id="formWarp" <? if($_POST["contact"] == "true"){ echo 'style="display:none" '; } ?>>
   <form method="POST" action="Contact.php">
     <input type="text" name="something"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="contact" value="true"/>
   </form>
```

You can include any other `<input>`'s inside the form.

Comment: This is kind of what we were going for. However, Our contact.php file is part of a larger contact form plugin. The html it puts out is derived from an $html php variable which seems to use its own special syntax. I just don't really know how to write that first line into our contact.php file

Comment: `public function html() 
    {     
        $html  = '<form action="#p01-contact' . $this->id . '" autocomplete="off" ';
        $html .= 'id="p01-contact' . $this->id . '" class="p01-contact" method="post">';
    
        $html .= $this->html_status();
        
    }`

It kinda of looks like that

Comment: is the function you posted able to be manipulated? or is that part of the CMS?

Comment: It can be manipulated. there is a GUI for the the plugin used by the CMS, but is really only used to configure which text fields are displayed and blacklists certain data entries like known spam e-mail addresses.

Comment: Is this function only called for the contact.php file?

Comment: I don't see it in any other files, so I have to think it is exclusive to just this file

Comment: How did you achieve hiding the form div then?